# MongoDB Populate Aggregate Unwind

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following data structure for my user model:

```
{
 _id: object,
 name: string,
 quotes: [ { quote: string, createdAt: date } ],
 friends: [ { _id: object } ] (this refers to the _id from the user model)
}
```

What i'd like to do is return this:

```
{
  quote: string,
  createdAt: date,
  _id: object (friend's)
}
{
  quote: string,
  createdAt: date,
  _id: object (friend's)
}
...
```

sorted by createdAt = recent to oldest

Comment: Sorry I guess the post was a little bare..  My profile will have a list of "friends" that are references to the _id from other's user model... I feel like it needs to populate first.. then the quotes within each friends model is just a _id reference to the quotes model.. so it needs to populate as well.. now from there I have my friends (user model) and quotes (quote model).. how do I get a simple output like friends' name, friend's quote, and createdAt?

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question is you want to unwind two array elements based on recent time.

```
db.user.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$quotes"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$friends"
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "quotes.createdAt": -1
        }
    }
])
```